# Github API branch history, how do I get it from the API

Tags: api, github, branch, history

How do I get the commits for a specific branch from the github API?

I know commits are not associated with one specific branch per se, but I want something similar to what you get from the command line when you type `git hist` or `git log`, only I want to do it in an automated way like using curl to access the api without having to clone a repo and checkout a branch.

Is there a way to do that?
I found in the API docs that you can get all commits for the whole repo, but that's not what I want.